# Has the media reevaluated Schiff's statements in light of the fact there was a second whistleblower?

Tags: united-states, media, impeachment

Only a few days ago the Washington Post [gave](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2019/10/04/schiffs-false-claim-his-committee-had-not-spoken-whistleblower/) Schiff "four pinocchios" for his statements regarding his early contacts with the whistleblower. Interestingly, this sentence was part of the WaPo conclusions:

> The explanation that Schiff was not sure it was the same whistleblower especially strains credulity.

But we now know [there is](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/10/06/politics/second-whistleblower-trump-ukraine/index.html) actually a second whistleblower in the Trump-Ukraine call. Does this change anything with respect to the truth value of Schiff's statements? Have any news outlets re-evaluated those statements in light of the fact that there were two whistleblowers?

Comment: Seems off topic, question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @Burt_Harris: Looking at your questions you may have the impression that this site is limited to "grand questions" like how do we fix fake news. But there is more stuff that is [on-topic here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "In just about any policy of substance, there are particular personalities that are central to its understanding [...]" (1/2)

Comment: Schiff's credibility in the impeachment process has been brought up by media like [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/10/03/politics/adam-schiff-under-scrutiny/index.html) and by [Trump himself](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/464466-trump-mocks-schiff-with-pinocchio-themed-video) with a pinocchios-based attack. (2/2)

Comment: [Here's one meta question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3091/5155) asking specifically if "the media" is on topic, [here's another one](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5155) asking if media funding is on topic.. there doesn't seem to be a general consensus yet. But "the media" didn't do anything to Schiff, there were stories written by some people and statements made by some politicians, so I think this question currently is overly broad.

Comment: Wasn't Schiff's main jab that he didn't have any contact with the whistleblower? It doesn't make it more truthful if Schiff was coordinating with 1 instead of 2.  And given that Schiff lied repeatedly for two years that he had concrete proof on Russian collusion, why would anyone give him the benefit of the doubt.